# django code 400, message Bad request version ('î\x9el\x00$\x13\x01\x13\x03\x13\x02À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À')

Tags: django

I was trying to implement 'Securing Django Admin login with OTP', however I can't login into the admin panel now. I removed the app from everywhere but still doesn't work. Any solution for this?

```
[05/Feb/2021 21:39:49] code 400, message Bad request version ('î\x9el\x00$\x13\x01\x13\x03\x13\x02À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À')
[05/Feb/2021 21:39:49] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Comment: It is telling you what the problem is. You are trying to access your development server through https:// instead of http AND/OR http requests are automatically redirected to https:// (I think something this library can do from the 2 seconds I looked at the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on development version you cant use `https` connection on your localhost so just turn your URL to `http` and error will be disappear.
ex:

> https://localhost:8000
>
> or
> https://127.0.0.1:8000

just turn it to

> http://localhost:8000
>
> or
> http://127.0.0.1:8000

also may be at `127.0.0.1:8000`